# Is there a way to create Visual Assist specific preprocessor sections?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, visual-assist

I have some complicated preprocessor macros which use the N-arg trick to count arguments and generate specific sub macro depending on the `__VA_ARG__` argument count. 
Visual Assist doesn't like that and it completely messes up the parsing and the error reports. 
I would like to know if any predefined macros (for example `__VAX__`or `__VISUAL_ASSIST__`) are defined in case of Visual assist parsing to implement specific code for him. If not, do you know any other way to avoid visual assist parsing a section or a way to give it a specific version of a macro ?

Answer (score 4):

You can give Visual Assist a specific version of a macro by creating a `va_stdafx.h` file. Inside this file place the simplified macro definitions you wish Visual Assist to see. Ensure the file ends with a blank line.

The process is described here:
https://support.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W302

Comment: Thanks ! I test this and give you my feedback !